# Mock setup returning null when the method is called using await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to unit test an action in an MVC controller but the mocked object is returning null.

I have a ClientProxy interface

```
public interface IClientProxy
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
}
```

With the following concrete implementation

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        ConfigureClient(httpClient);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await Task.Run(() => GetResultFromResponse<T>(response));
    }
}
```

This is my action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var categories = await _proxy.Get<PagedResults<Category>>("/category/get");
    return View("index", null, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories));
}
```

And this is the unit test class

```
public class CategoryControllerTests
{
    private readonly CategoryController _controller;
    private readonly Mock<IClientProxy> _mockProxy;

    public CategoryControllerTests()
    {
        _mockProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
        _controller = new CategoryController(_mockProxy.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task IndexPageRenders()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fakeResult = new PagedResults<Category>
        {
            Paging = new Paging
            {
                Page = 1, 
                PageSize = 10,
                TotalRecords = 2
            },
            Results = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Category One" },
                new Category { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Category Two" }
            }
        };

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fakeResult);

        _mockProxy.Setup(p => p.Get<PagedResults<Category>>(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(fakeResult);

        // Act
        var action = await _controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        _mockProxy.Verify(p => p.Get<PagedResults<Category>>(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
}
```

Currently the mocked object setup for the get method is not getting hit, and categories are null (the Verify is failing, implying that the mocked method is never called). However, if I remove the await keyword from the action then the categories are returned. I'd rather not remove the await just to pass the test as it's there for a good reason, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you serializing your model when returning from view?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently the mocked object setup for the get method is not getting hit, and categories are null (the Verify is failing, implying that the mocked method is never called).

That would mean that the mocked object was not passed as a dependency to the controller being tested and as such is not being invoked when the test is being exercised.

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates how one would setup and exercise a test in such a scenario.

The follow were used

```
public class MyModel {
    public int MyIntProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IClientProxy {
    Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
}

public class MyController : Controller {
    IClientProxy _proxy;

    public MyController(IClientProxy _proxy) {
        this._proxy = _proxy;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        var categories = await _proxy.Get<MyModel>("/category/get");
        return View(categories);
    }
}
```

And following test was used with MSTest, Moq and Fluent Assertions where is flowed to completion and passed.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyController_Should {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _Render_Index_Page() {
        // Arrange
        var fakeResult = new MyModel {
            MyIntProperty = 0,
            MyStringProperty = "Hello World."
        };

        var _mockProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
        _mockProxy
            .Setup(_ => _.Get<MyModel>(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(fakeResult);

        var _controller = new MyController(_mockProxy.Object);

        // Act
        var action = await _controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        _mockProxy.Verify(_ => _.Get<MyModel>(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));

        action.Should().NotBeNull();

        var model = action.Model;
        model.Should().NotBeNull()
            .And.BeOfType<MyModel>()
            .And.Be(fakeResult);
    }
}
```

I would suggest reviewing this example and then comparing it to how you designed your test to see if you can identify what may be causing your problem.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the entire test class. As you'll see I am injecting the mock proxy int categoryController in the constructor. If you can see anything else I'm missing, please do point it out as I'm banging my head against the wall by now. Thanks

Comment: @TreeFrog is this a typo in your update `_mockProxy.Setup(p => p.Get<T>(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(fakeResult);` because you will notice that you have to use the actual type for the mock to match.

Comment: Good spot @Nkosi. I had been "playing" trying different things and hadn't reverted it fully.